# Can anyone help me what this p-value mean?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, p-value

I'm working at some research for claim reserve and I use the glmreserve (Over-dispersed Poisson) function in R. It generate p-value and I don't know what's that mean. Can someone help me what is this p-value mean ? is it for the model?
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! What does a p-value ever mean?

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite clear which p-value you are asking about, but I'll assume it's the `Pr(>|t|)` values in the last column.

Those are p-values for the two-sided test of whether that coefficient is equal to zero.  If the true value of the coefficient is zero, expect a random value approximately uniformly distributed between 0 and 1.

Those small numbers `"< 2e-16"` aren't very likely from a uniform distribution, so the classical interpretation is that there is evidence that those coefficients are non-zero.

On the other hand, 0.0986 isn't all that unusually small, so that one might really be zero.

Comment: This is a confusing answer.  `Origin` is explicitly a factor variable, which means it ought to be tested as a chunk rather than by individual values.  "Might really be zero" is ambiguous and needs interpretation, because all the estimates are *relative* to the base class whose estimate is given by the Intercept term, which is much larger than any of the other estimates.  The question is about which variables to keep in the model, but in what sense could one remove one of the values of this factor variable while keeping all the others??

Comment: @whuber, I don't know if the question was "about which variables to keep in the model".  I was explaining what tests the p-values in the last column were addressing.  Like most tests based on automatic output, the tests don't necessarily make sense.  I'd suggest you should post an answer that better addresses your interpretation of the question.

Comment: @whuber- I don’t think you meant “given by the Intercept term””